# How to check if a Class.forName() implements a particular interface?

Tags: java

I am using the string to get a Class name and the using the Class.forName() to get a Class.

Now I want to know if this class is an instance of another class (in this case java.lang.AutoCloseable).

My code is

```
Class c = Class.forName("java.io.FileInputStream");
if(c instanceof java.lang.AutoCloseable){
     //detected that FileInputStream implements AutoCloseable
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I have also tried c.newInstance() and c.getClass().newInstance() but neither work and throw exceptions. Please help!

Comment: Try taking a look at [`Class#isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)) or is it [`Class#isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class))...?

Comment: The left operand of `instanceof` is, as one might expect, an object _instance_, not a class or instance of `Class<?>`. To test the class itself you should use the `isAssignableFrom()` method of `java.lang.Class`

Answer (score 1):

```
    Class c = Class.forName("java.io.FileInputStream");
if(c instanceof java.lang.AutoCloseable){
     //detected that FileInputStream implements AutoCloseable
}
```

TO

```
Class c = Class.forName("java.io.FileInputStream");
if(java.lang.AutoCloseable.class.isAssignableFrom(c)){
     //detected that FileInputStream implements AutoCloseable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
boolean isComparable = Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(cls));
```